# Daily loss limit, intra-day, in tradingview?

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

Re: daily los limits in TradingView

Can anyone tell me how to set up a auto daily loss limit in trading view?

I know there are many things possible with the pine editor, and I found this article explaining how to do it, but looks like it’s only for back testing. I’m not a programmer, so￼ this is a bit over my head. ￼

What I’m wanting to do is set up the daily loss limit for my live sessions.

Any help would be appreciated thank you! ￼￼￼￼￼

￼

Answer (score 0):

You're not a programmer but the solution I fear needs some very easy pinescripting

[https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_strategy{dot}risk{dot}max_intraday_loss](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_strategy%7Bdot%7Drisk%7Bdot%7Dmax_intraday_loss)

This is the function to call for doing what you want